# Ed script only works if typed slowly

Tags: scripting, stdin, ed

In [this context](https://github.com/gitlabhq/mysql-postgresql-converter/issues/12) I've encountered a situation where `ed file < script` would print `?` and exit with error 2, while typing or pasting the commands from `script` one at a time worked fine. Even having a shell process pass the file through one line at a time with a `sleep` in between worked correctly. So it seems to me as though my version of `ed`, which is the one from MacOS 10.12, has problems if commands appear at inconvenient times.

1. Why doesn't ed simply avoid reading stdin until it's ready to process whatever commands it gets? Or am I misinterpreting the situation?
2. The error message `?` isn't too helpful. In an interactive session I could type `h` afterwards to get an error message, according to the man page. But with input from a non-TTY it exits immediately. Is there some way to get at the error message in this case, too?
3. Is this a known issue? If so, are there any suggested workarounds instead of passing the commands in slowly? What versions of ed would be affected?

Comment: Yeah, I had this too... with `gnu ed`. It only happened when piping (`|`) the commands to `ed`, it never happened when using here-docs or here-strings so my advice is to try using a here-doc to pass the commands to `ed` (e.g. `ed -s somefile.sql <<IN...`)

Comment: Item #2 really should be a separate question in its own right.

Comment: And don_crissti has just demonstrated _why_ it should be a separate question in its own right.  A real question and answer would cover something that don_crissti has missed and that is inappropriate in question comments.

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be caused by carriage returns in the `ed` script. Copying and pasting a piece of text would not transfer these to the running `ed` process, but if they are in a script file, then I can understand that `ed` got confused.

GNU `ed` exits with an exit status of 2 "to indicate a corrupt or
       invalid input file", which supports the speculation that it may be a DOS formatted script file. However, the default `ed` on macOS is BSD `ed` and the exit codes are not properly documented in the manual.  Looking at the (OpenBSD) source, it does look like most errors causing this exit code has to do with the reading of the script file though.

To remove the `\r` before each newline (will perform an in-place edit):

```
printf '%s\n' ',s/\r$//' 'wq' | ed -s file
```

The carriage returns would have got there from having written the script in a Windows editor, for example, or in any editor that saved the file as a DOS formatted text file.

Question 1: I'm pretty sure it does.

Question 2 has to do with the rather terse diagnostic messages that `ed` produces (`?`, most of the time). If you start your editing script with a call to the `H` function, any error will be verbose rather than the plain `?`, as if you had typed `h` after an error.  This does not help if there are carriage returns at the end of each line though, as these would prevent `ed` from recognizing `H` as a valid command.

Question 3: I have used GNU `ed` (1.14.2) and the BSD `ed` on OpenBSD, and I have not seen this issue caused by feeding `ed` commands "too quickly".

Comment: Reminds me of https://www.gnu.org/fun/jokes/ed-msg.html *Note the consistent user interface and error reportage. Ed is generous enough to flag errors, yet prudent enough not to overwhelm the novice with verbosity*